# Erro al crear pom proyect

Tags: netbeans-11.3

Estoy haciendo un curso e intento crear un Pom proyect con netbeans pero no me deja me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

existe algo similar para crear en Eclipse?

Comment: Ahí no se ve un error sino un warning. Posiblemente es porque el directorio no existe (aún). Qué pasa si le das Finish? Como consejo para la vida: EVITA usar directorios con espacio en el nombre cuando construyas cosas. Históricamente esto genera líos en varios casos a menos que uno tome precauciones y pues... es más fácil evitarlo.

Comment: no lo crea si le doy afinish no hace nada.

Comment: En tu captura se ve el `pom.xml` en ProjectFiles :V.

Comment: eso es otro proyecto no el que estoy intentado crear